# Save labels html into array javascript using jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a html code like this :

```
<p style:"text-align:center"><label>Question1</label></p>
<p style:"text-align:center"><label>Question2</label></p>
<p style:"text-align:center"><label>Question3</label></p>
```

So, i'm using the jquery selector '>' to get the especifically the text of labels into elements 'p' (Because i have other elements into other elements 'p'). My selector is this :

```
<script>
       var labels= $('p > label').text();
       console.log(labels);
</script>
```

The point is that i'm getting a string like : "Question1Question2Question3" instead of an array with the elements. I'm so new using jquery, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.each()` and push every single value into an array.

```js
var arr = [];
$('p > label').each(function(){
  arr.push($(this).html());
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style:"text-align:center"><label>Question1</label></p>
<p style:"text-align:center"><label>Question2</label></p>
<p style:"text-align:center"><label>Question3</label></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/): translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

The snippet:

```js
var labels = $.map($('p > label'), function(ele, idx) {
    return ele.textContent;
});

console.log(labels);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p style="text-align:center"><label>Question1</label></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><label>Question2</label></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><label>Question3</label></p>
```